# Why does these two objects are not of same type in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a variable defined as type:-
`final Future Function(BuildContext context, FormModel model) onSubmitCallBack;`

I am assigning to it a function which takes **2** parameters of type **BuildContext** and **Institute**, and returns Future.

Note that Institute is a Subclass of FormModel.

There is no error at compile time. But at runtime I get this error.

> Expected a value of type '(BuildContext, FormModel) => Future', but got one of type '(BuildContext, Institute) => Future'

Any Ideas why? I expected this to run since Institute is subclass of FormModel.

The FormModel and Institute class:

```
class FormModel{
  const FormModel();
}

class Institute extends FormModel {
  final int? id;
  final String name;
  final String? addedOn;
  final String? updateOn;

  const Institute({
    this.id,
    required this.name,
    this.addedOn,
    this.updateOn
  });
}
```

Comment: I have removed the functional programming tag. Please do not add tags to questions without reading the tag descriptions first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because every `Institite` is a `FormModel` but not every `FormModel` is an `Institute`.

Consider having yet another extension like `class Study extends FormModel`. In such case your assignment is unsafe because your callback implementation accepts only `Institute` but yet it can be provided with `Study` which would simply break.

In other words, you expect this to work (pseudocode):

```
final Future Function(BuildContext context, FormModel model) onSubmitCallBack;   
final Future Function(BuildContext ctx, Institute model) instituteCallback;


onSubmitCallback = instituteCallback;

onSubmitCallback(ctx,new Study()); /// WHOOOOOOPS
```

now you have a problem as `Study` is not an `Institute` and yet it would have to be passed as such.

Comment: I understood the problem, what do you suggest as a solution? For now I have just changed the type of 'onSubmitCallback' to `Function`